# why can one user register a geodatabase with the server and the other user can not?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-10.3

So i have two users; arcgis_db and AD\raclark, one can publish a service the other can not.

It all goes fine till i get to the 'service editor' screen and click 'analyze'. One user, arcgis_db comes back clean and ready to go the other user AD\raclark gets the dread 00179 error 'layers data source must be registered' however the the database i am using is registered with my ArcGIS Server site.

When i look at the server logs i see this...

Server Log

"The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Underlying DBMS error[[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.No extended error.]"

So i can not figure it out. one user can publish a service the other user can not and it stalls out when it comes to registering data with the server.

So what is about the users that is causing this?

arcgis_db is mapped to the 'public' and 'sysadmin' server roles; it is also mapped to the 'Facilities' database as 'db_owner'. So it is the dbo and and 'sysadmin'. its also SQL server authenticated login.

AD\raclark is a mapped to the 'public' server role; he is also mapped to the 'Faclities' database as 'public' and 'data_editor' role (data editor role is given SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges on each of the feature datasets / feature classes in the database). He is OS authenticated login.

Also...

SQL Server, Windows Server 2012R, drivers are current and correct, arcgis 10.3, arcgis server 10.3

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering Randall. If you could take your edit and roll it into an "answer" and mark yourself correct that would be great and you would earn some upvotes from me!!

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: @Conor  Done. Sorry about the delay

Answer (score 2):

It had to do with how the AGS (ArcGIS Server) account was set up. The AGS is a local account not a AD account because of this it use db authentication not OS authentication. So because the AGS account is db authentication all accounts that are going to register data with the server have to use the same authentication mode as the AGS account when connecting to the database, in this case db authentication.

AGS uses db authentication then the users have to use db authentication, AGS uses OS authentication then the users have to use OS authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Use database authentication in connection strings

or

2. Use a domain user which has access to the database for "ArcGIS Server" service